# confusion between overlay, overlayitem and itemizedoverley

Tags: android, google-maps, overlay, itemizedoverlay

I wanting to create an app which displays a map and on top of this map, the roads and points of interests will be painted as lines and ovals. These lines and ovals will have listeners attached to them so the user can drag them around or delete them.

I am using openstreetmaps with osmdroid however it seems to be exactly the same as Google Maps.

I was thinking of extending the OverlayItem class to represent a point of interest or a road. The Overlay class would be extended and contain an ArrayList of these extended OverlayItems.

The draw method of the Overlay class would be overridden and would paint all of the OverlayItem contained in the arraylist.

This Overlay class is then added to the MapView.

I am not sure if this would work because a lot of tutorials use an ItemizedOverlay. What exactly is this and should I be using it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `ItemizedOverlay` is a class extending `Overlay` (as you want to do) and mostly completed (you still need to extend it and fill the specific parts) in order to add a list of `Drawables` to the map in specified `Geopoints` (using a list of `OverlayItem`). It also implements `onTap()` for the items added.

So bottom line, `ItemizedOverlay` is a pre-coded class aiming what seems to be your objective.

**Limitations**

It may not be the best solution for all your overlays ...

Examples where it would be better to use your own calss extending overlay:

- If your `POI` requires a `Drawable` that needs to be rotated at
  runtime (i.e. an arrow pointing in a changing direction)
- If you want to draw a route without markers
- If you want to draw something that can't be easly made from a drawable

Regards.

Comment: Hi, I read that `ItemizedOverlay` is only recommended for a small number of overlay items. I will have several hundred points as well as a relatively large number of lines to represent roads.

Do you think just extending Overlay would be the way to go here? I don't think I will be using `Drawable`, I am just painting simple colored circles and lines.

Also, if I do just extend Overlay and have a list of `POI` points. Is there a way to assign touch listeners to each specific point?

Comment: 1- If you are using so many points, you will have better performance with your own overlay (assuming correct coding). 2- You should think carefully about adding several hundred POI's to map. If they are too close, it will be a mess. 3- I suggest you to use `Drawble`whenever possible, as in general `canvas.drawBitmap()` is much faster then `canvas.drawCircle()`. 4- For the listener, the best approac is to override `onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev, MapView mapView)` and test the event (x,y) coordinates against the bounds of each one of your POI´s.

Answer (score 0):

An `ItemizedOverlay` essentially does what you're talking about: it contains an itemized list of `OverlayItem` objects to draw.