# How to implement a draggable ExtendedOverlayItem on OSMDroid?

Tags: java, android, drag, osmdroid

I'm developing a feature to drag a map overlay (using `ExtendedOverlayItem` class), using `osmdroid` and `OSMBonusPack`.

This question talks about a possible solution:

[Unable to implement onTouchEvent (Drag & Drop) with Osmdroid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7986025/unable-to-implement-ontouchevent-drag-drop-with-osmdroid/30124085)

So, my questions are:

1 - Where do I put that code?

2 - Should I create a new class? extending from which other class?

Additional Similar questions:

[How do you implement OverlayItem to be draggable? (Using ItemizedIconOverlays if possible)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7407338/how-do-you-implement-overlayitem-to-be-draggable-using-itemizediconoverlays-if)

[confusion between overlay, overlayitem and itemizedoverley](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13671475/confusion-between-overlay-overlayitem-and-itemizedoverley)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved my problem by updating the [OSMBonusPack Library](https://github.com/MKergall/osmbonuspack). And the following code was used to implement the draggable marker:

```
import org.osmdroid.bonuspack.overlays.Marker;
import org.osmdroid.bonuspack.overlays.Marker.OnMarkerDragListener;
import org.osmdroid.util.GeoPoint;

public static void applyDraggableListener(Marker poiMarker) {
        poiMarker.setDraggable(true);
        poiMarker.setOnMarkerDragListener(new OnMarkerDragListener() {
                @Override
                public void onMarkerDragStart(Marker marker) {}

                @Override
                public void onMarkerDragEnd(Marker marker) {
                        GeoPoint geopoint = marker.getPosition();        
                }

                @Override
                public void onMarkerDrag(Marker marker) {}
        });                
}
```

Comment: hi can you say what's your  OSMBonusPack Library version? because in my last version 6 I don't have  Marker

Answer (score 1):

As you are already using OSMBonusPack: just use the Marker overlay - which is draggable (BTW, ExtendedOverlayItem is now obsolete).

Comment: Yes i'm using, but the older one. I'll update my project and try to do that. Thanks a lot.